# Search string for weird newline?

Tags: .net, string, newline

I am writing software for a serial port.  In .NET there is the function SerialPort.GetPortNames().  This returns a string array containing a comport name for each comport on your system.
For example, it will return COM4, COM5 etc.
However, in the last few months, Silicon Labs drivers have a bug where this .NET function returns a string that looks like this:
COM18\0즎\uffff퍸鐸즎\uffff\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ƀ
This comes directly from visual studio in debug mode.

Actually it is 129 characters long.
The problem is, the users of my software have in many cases upgraded to the latest driver and this bug is in there.  So I am trying to release a patch that parses the string but I cannot seem to figure out how to do so.
I tried if port.contains("\0") as well as if port.contains("\\0") and this is not found.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: if you copy from debug mode, symbols often become different from actual values.
what do you get if you do string[index], being index - position of '\0'? try also (int)string[index] to get code. (int)'\0' has value of 0

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  Based on what you said  I used an IndexOf('\0') to determine where in the string the control 0 character was.  If a -1 was returned, the string is OK otherwise I can just extract all characters up to the '\0';